# Why doesn't my VPN client transition between mobile to Wi-Fi?

Tags: mobile-data, vpn, openvpn

I'm experiencing slightly odd behavior from my VPN on a Note 4, Android 5.0.1.  It appears to work as far as routing my traffic is concerned, but if I leave an area with Wi-Fi and come back, it stays routing everything though my mobile connection.  For some reason it doesn't seem to be notified the route table has been updated and the default route has changed.  If I manually disconnect and reconnect the VPN, it makes the connection through the Wi-Fi like I'd expect.

I find this strange, because I've done this on two other phones without issue, the handoff was handled automatically.  They were both running Android 4.4 at the latest.  Has something changed, is there anything I can do to make this transition properly?  Is something just wrong with my VPN app((s) - I've tried two, to the same server.)  Any suggestions?